# Spartacus storefront not showing "Add to wishlist" button when logged in

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have an environment of SAP Commerce 2005.0 and Spartacus 2.0.0 running the Electronics accelerator with spartacussampledataaddon. Both do not have any custom code.

When I am not logged in and navigate to a Product Detail page, I see the "Sign in to add to wishlist" as expected.

However, after logging in (with an existing user), and viewing the same PDP, there is no button at all. The product is in stock. In the source of the page I see only this:

```
<cx-add-to-wishlist><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}--><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}--><!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
}--><!--container--></cx-add-to-wishlist>
```

What could explain the absence of the button?

UPDATE: I just found out that if I register a new customer, and then login, the button is showing as expected.

Comment: Is it a new user that you just registered or an existing user? If it's an existing user you should see a GET request when opening the PDP to `/carts` that will return the wish list. Do you see that request and could you add the response form it?

Comment: No, when opening the PDP I see no request to `/carts`. I only see requests to `/products`, `/pages`, `/components`, `/notificationpreferences` & `/productinterests`

Comment: Interesting... in the `/pages` request do you see the `AddToWishListComponent` component in the `ProductSummarySlot`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I also found out later that it the button does show correctly for newly registered users. It seems that for newly registered users, a default wishlist cart is saved to the database. But it seems that users created through other means (e.g. ImpEx) do not have this - though it could be that I hadn't added all the required SAP Commerce extensions yet when those users were created.